# Why is this relation logical?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I am currently working on some homework for a PDEs course. I found myself up against the following statement.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int u(x)dx=\int u(x,t)dx$$

Why is this statement true?  I've looked around, but haven't seen an answer that has made sense to me.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

The question is regarding the heat equation.
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^L c\rho u(x)dx=[\phi (x) - \phi(x+\Delta x)]+\int_0^L Q dx$$

Where $c\rho=1, \phi (x) - \phi(x+\Delta x)=\phi (0) - \phi(L)$, and $Q=1$. Where $c$ is the specific heat, $\rho$ is the mass density, $\phi$ is the flux, $u(x)$ is the temperature at any given position, and $Q$ is the heat energy.

By Fourier's equation for heat flux, and by substituting given values, this becomes
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^L u(x)dx= -K_0(u_x(0)-u_x(L))+\int_0^Ldx$$

The right-hand side becomes $0$ after performing a few operations. In my class notes, my professor then states that 
$$ u(x,t)=0 \Rightarrow \int_0^L u(x,t) dx =constant $$
Which then brings me to my original question.

EDIT 2: I apologize to anyone who saw the nightmare that was my title. It is fixed now.

Comment: In what way does the left-hand side depend on $t$?

Comment: What is $u$? On the left-hand side it is a function of one variable, on the right-hand side it takes two variables. Are those two $u$-s distinct functions? Is might be a function of two variables, with some $t=\text{const.}$ assumed on LHS, but I'm not sure if $\frac d{dt}$ will make any sense then...

Comment: @carmichael561 , I've added an edit. Does this help at all?

Comment: What comes next? It might be easier to guess what was meant to be written if we can see what he does with it.

Comment: @Hurkyl We then used initial conditions to find an unknown constant. She said that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\int u(x,t)dx=\int f(x)dx$ . This left us with a equation for the temperature, u(x).

Comment: From your explanation it looks like it's as simple as $\frac d{dt} \int u dx = 0$ implying $\int u dx$ is constant in time, but your question is very unclear - where does $u(x,t) = 0$ come from? And where are you even getting your supposed $\frac d{dt} \int u = \int u $ from?